# Why is the pod is showing running even when the node is down?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The node named Kube worker node is down for more than 12 hour, but the pod is showing running. Why kubernetes did not updated in that much of time ?

```
# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS     ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
kube-worker-node   NotReady   <none>                 17h   v1.20.2

pix:/home/ciasto# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
flask-776b878dbc-krtd6   1/1     Running   0          17h   192.168.254.2    kube-worker-node   <none>           <none>
redis-596bbd776-q6s2n    1/1     Running   0          15h   192.168.42.130   rockpi             <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Hello, could you tell more about your setup? How have you configured your cluster (is it on premise, is it a cloud-solution)? Which version of Kubernetes are you running (apart from that single node). Please include the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your setup.

Comment: it is on premise. and I am using Kubernetes v1.20.1 on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because of missing `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute` taint on the node. You can check it using bellow command

```
kubectl describe nodes kube-worker-node  | grep Taints
```

Please check the related issue in github [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98851)

Comment: How does taint attribute is assigned to the node?

Comment: It's automatically added by node controller when the node is not ready

Comment: I just checked its set to NoSchedule

`Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule`

Comment: if its automatically added by node controller, that means it has failed in this cluster.

Comment: it's a bug being fixed in this pr https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96876